# How to specify port in azure container instance?

Tags: azure, azure-container-instances

One of my container listens to port 80 in logs it show this  `Now listening on: http://[::]:80`, but i want to expose port 5000 for it, in docker it was quite simple `5000:80` but how do i do this in azure container instance, i am deploying container using yaml file. There isn't anything given in documentation for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update as of late 2020: It does support port mapping today, see [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-custom-container?pivots=container-linux#configure-port-number):

> By default, App Service assumes your custom container is listening on either port 80 or port 8080. If your container listens to a different port, set the WEBSITES_PORT app setting in your App Service app.

(Before 2020 you couldn't...)

Comment: The link you provided seems broken.

Comment: Yep. Sure is broken.

Comment: Yup, they removed the whole feedback site and all the votes all together :-(

Comment: This answer appears to be related to App Service, which is not the same as Container Instances.